# Use softkeyboard for google tv

Tags: android, navigation, focus, android-softkeyboard, google-tv

Although it is possible to embed the keyboardView in google tv, it seems there is no possibility to navigate through the single keys with the dpad. Is there any way to make the keys focusable?

I know there is no need to use the softkeyboard in google tv because the remote control already has one but the customer explicitly wishes it.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try sub-classing and overriding the onKeyUp event handler.